# How to use Shared Projects in Universal Windows Platform (Windows 10)?

Tags: windows-10, windows-10-mobile

With Windows 8.1 developers could create shared projects that were common to a Windows Phone project and Windows 8.1 project and have non-common code in different folders. Upon build for each platform the corresponding folder is used. I am migrating an app to UWP and I can't find a way to use this functionality. I realize I can continue to use Windows 8.1 project template but I want to use other UAP features like x:Bind. I am not a fan of the whole responsive design thing and what is more I already have custom UI for tablet and phone so I would really like to use shared projects if possible. Any hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Device Family specific folders should fit your needs.

Here is a blog post with code samples: http://igrali.com/2015/08/02/three-ways-to-set-specific-devicefamily-xaml-views-in-uwp/

Comment: But aren't Windows Phone and tablet (say Surface) the same device family (mobile)?

Comment: Windows Phone reports as "Mobile" and a Surface reports as "Desktop".

Comment: Does a Surface in tablet mode still report as Desktop?

Comment: Yep, even in Tablet Mode the Surface still registers as "Desktop"

Comment: This feature only works for views right? That doesn't make me very happy but at least it is something.

Comment: Yes this is for XAML. In code you can use AnalyticsInfo.VersionInfo.DeviceFamily or ApiInformation.IsEventPresent to determine the DeviceFamily or if an API is available.